# Scikit-learn. Какова вероятность вхождения в группу

Tags: python, numpy, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

```
for doc, category in zip(docs_new, predicted):
 print('%r => %s' % (doc, twenty_train.target_names[category]))
```

Как узнать с какой вероятностью алгоритм определил, что текст относится к данной группе?

Вот полный код:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_files

categories = ['first', 'second', 'third']
twenty_train = load_files('db', categories=categories, shuffle=False, encoding='utf-8')

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(twenty_train.data)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
print(X_train_tfidf.shape)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, twenty_train.target)

docs_new = [str1, str2]
X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(docs_new)
X_new_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_new_counts)

predicted = clf.predict(X_new_tfidf)

for doc, category in zip(docs_new, predicted):
    print('%r => %s' % (doc, twenty_train.target_names[category]))
```

Comment: укажите каким классификатором вы пользовались. Лучше привести соответствующую часть кода... Что так``ое `docs_new`? Как выглядит `twenty_train`?

Comment: @MaxU Добавил полный код выше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [predict_proba()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.predict_proba).

Пример:

Исходные данные:

```
In [19]: X = np.random.randint(5, size=(6, 100))

In [20]: y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

In [21]: clf = MultinomialNB()
```

обучаем модель:

```
In [22]: clf.fit(X, y)
Out[22]: MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
```

предсказываем класс:

```
In [23]: clf.predict(X[2:3])
Out[23]: array([3])
```

все классы:

```
In [24]: clf.classes_
Out[24]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

предсказываем вероятности для всех классов:

```
In [25]: clf.predict_proba(X[2:3])
Out[25]: array([[  4.69205412e-31,   9.16479809e-30,   1.00000000e+00,   2.47492746e-28,   2.13947776e-31,   2.04949820e-34]])
```

Comment: Я, к сожалению, только начинаю. Хотите сказать, что это нельзя применить к моему коду?

Comment: @user277248, почему нельзя - просто вместо `clf.predict(...)` воспользуйтесь `clf.predict_proba(...)`

Comment: Класс. Спасибо! А может быть вы мне еще и какой-то справочный материал порекомендуете. Прямо чтобы совсем для чайников:)